# Android how to center text of chip with fixed size?

Tags: android, material-design

I have a chip with 100dp of width but the text is not centered how I can center the text.

I use androidx with material library, I've tried put `android:textAlignment="center"` and `android:gravity="center"` but not work

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:id="@+id/chip"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="7:00" />
```

I have this

[image: chip]

I want this

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of what you achieved so far?

Comment: yes, I updated the post

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. Using `android:gravity="center"` you should have in logcat `W/Chip: Chip text must be vertically center and start aligned`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

just now I faced with the same problem, and I solved it by set a chip property: `android: textAlignment = "center"`. I tested your example and it works fine too, here the code that I tested:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chip"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7:00"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also make sure that you don't set or change a chip's text alignment somewhere in your code.

Comment: chip.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER); if you want to do it programatically.

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer:**

Chips aren't meant to be used the way you are trying to use them. They are supposed to wrap your content. Therefore there isn't a **clean way** to align the text in the center.
There is a workaround tho, you can use [Chip_textEndPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip.html#attr_Chip_textEndPadding) and [Chip_textStartPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip.html#attr_Chip_textStartPadding) attributes, which will be kinda awkward I guess.

I don't really know what you are trying to achieve, I mean, what is your why? Is it a button? Is it suppose just to show some text?
**Please describe the feature, or at least, part of it.**

**Anyway:**

According to the [material design guidelines](https://material.io/components/chips/#)

> Chips allow users to enter information, make selections, filter content, or trigger actions. Chips should appear dynamically as a group of multiple interactive elements. Unlike buttons, which should be a consistent and familiar call to action, one that a user expects to appear as the same action in the same general area.

Does your feature as anything to do with this?

In case you want a clickable, circular component you can simply use [material button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/).

There is a similar question that was asked at [github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/68).

Answer (score 1):

as others said you can use textAlignment ...but i wanted to tell you that if your using a custom font it wont be perfectly vertically aligned.   you can [check here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1424) for explanation.

so i would make a custom style that inherits from chip styles and set the font padding for usage like this:

```
 <style name="customStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>

   ******* <item name="android:includeFontPadding">true</item> *************
  </style>
```

then for the text appearance you can make another style:

```
<style name="CustomChipTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">?attr/myFont</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
  </style>
```

dont forget to force a bridge theme in xml:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      style="@style/customStyle"
      ****  android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge" ****
***** android:textAppearance="@style/CustomChipTextAppearance"  *******
      app:chipMinHeight="38dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      app:chipStrokeWidth="2dp" 
      app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
      tools:chipText="my chip" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isTextAlignmentResolved`,
For example, `chipname.isTextAlignmentResolved()` to do this programmatically.